# How to play different sounds each time I click a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to play a diferent sound each time I press a button (mini game for kids so they can guess the animal sound).

In JS i have:

```
var lion = new Audio("http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Lion03.wav");
```

In the HTML I use:

```
onclick="lion.play()"
```

Is it possible to use this method for a 6 sound program?

Answer (score 3):

You should add the listener via JavaScript:

```
var sounds = [
  new Audio("/sounds/Lion03.wav"),
  new Audio("/sounds/Zebra03.wav"),
  new Audio("/sounds/SpaghettiMonster.wav")
];

var el = document.getElementById('my_id');
el.addEventListener(function() {
  // Take random sound from list of sounds:
  var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length];
  sound.play();
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="my_id">click for sound</div>
```

Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but your code doesn't seem to work...

Here's the JS i used:

var sounds = [
  new Audio("http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Lion03.wav"),
  new Audio("http://www.laffertyranch.org/sounds/eagle.wav"),
  new Audio("http://files.anitalink.com/gamecache/hl/svencoop/sound/mw/monkey1.wav")
];

var el = document.getElementsById('animals');
el.addEventListener(function() {
  // Take random sound from list of sounds:
  var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length];
  sound.play();
});

And the HTML:

<button id='animals'>Click Here</button>

Comment: Thanks for your patience in advance

No, i've tried the http...I think there's som something wrong with the sintax:
var el = document.getElementById('animals');
el.addEventListener(function() {
  // Take random sound from list of sounds:
  var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length];
  sound.play();
});

I use brackets and the parentisis and curly braces of the eventlistener function don't match...also, with this code, other programas in the main JS file stoped working. Tried to fix it but I didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I use the framework to develop games,and it helps a lot
And it is easy to add listener event:

```
//To get a random number to playsound
var playNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
//playsound
this.win.playSoundEffect("sound_" + playNumber + ".mp3")
```

just 2 lines code
and here is the link for example:[**example link**](http://studio.holaverse.cn/apprun.html?mode=preview&user_id=73&game_key=03690fd552554daa9ed553e6534657bd&company_id=7)

and you can push F12 to see which sound it plays(you'd better use chrome)

I think it is really easy to develop games by using framework.

If you are interested in framework,here is the online framework link,you could test yourself **online**:[**hola studio**](http://studio.holaverse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

very interesting game you have thought of. I am happy to contribute to anything that will help kids education. Anyways I think this might help you. Let me know if have any questions, but this takes more of an OOP approach.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m92mf7kL/

```
var Animal = function(animal, audio) {
this.animal = animal;
  this.audio = audio;
  return this;
};

Animal.prototype = {
    playSound: function() {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = this.audio;
    audio.play();
  }
};

// Create animal objects
var chimp = new Animal("chimp", "http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Chimp01.wav"),
        dog = new Animal("dog", "http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Dog01.wav"),
    donkey = new Animal("donkey", "http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Donkey01.wav"),
    goat = new Animal("Goat", "http://www.thewavsite.com/Animals/Goat.wav");

var animals = [chimp, dog, donkey, goat];

function playRandomAnimal() {
     var sound = animals[Math.floor(Math.random() * animals.length)];
   sound.playSound();
}
```

HTML

```
<button onClick="playRandomAnimal()">
Play Sound
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and code...yours seem interesting also but I have to say it's a bit earlier for me because i'm still learning JS/Jquery, and this little game is for a course project...But i'll keep yours in mind
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery this time and the HTML audio tag combined with the previous code and it worked:

HTML:

Click here 
and guess who 
wants to eat you!

JS(jQuery):

$(function () {

```
var sons = ["http://www.geolution.nl/dieren/dierengeluiden/download/wolf_11.wav",
```

"http://www.studiowan.com/ICAN/BRUITAGES/Animals/Bear%20Growl%2002.wav"];

```
$(".click-texto").click(function () {
    var rand = sons[Math.floor(Math.random() * sons.length)];
    $("#audio1").attr('src', rand);
    $("#audio1")[0].play();
```

});
 });